# How to translate in django a complex variable with filter and idx

Tags: django

Is someone know how to translate in Django a complex variable with filter (|) and customtag (idx) like:

```
<li data-role="list-divider">{{ controlItem|idx:0|upper }}</li>
```

I have no problem with simple variable like:

```
{% trans controlSubitem.name %}
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
{% with controlItem|idx:0|upper as variable %}
    {% trans variable %}
{% endwith %}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#with

Comment: with 
{% with sector|idx:1 as variable %}
    {% trans variable %}
{% endwith %}

but this time I try with 
{% with sector|idxPlus1:forloop.counter as variable %}
    {% trans variable %}
{% endwith %}
and it doesn't work!

Do you know how to resolve the translation with this specific variable?

Comment: The problem will be that the value of the current variable is not translated in some po file. What is the value of the variable, before and now? is there some translation of this value in some po file?

Comment: this variable refer to the sector attributes stock in my postgresql database. All the values were translate in my Po file and with first solution you gave it works perfectly! but in the case of idxPlus1:forloop.counter he show me no result in my dashboard display. Without trans variable the result are displayed normally in their origin language (english).